# Make logo start at 0.8 opacity

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I've written a bit of jQuery code to help me animate my website's logo.

It's supposed to fade in from the top over one second to 80% opacity, after which it has the potential to fade back and forth from 80% to 100% opacity upon mouseover.

Currently, my webpage fades in the logo from the top over one second as it's supposed to, but it fades into full opacity and only gets to 80% once I hover my mouse over and then move it off. The mouseover works as it should after that.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fadeInTime = 1000;

    $('.navigation .logo').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 0);
    $('.right ul').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 0);

    $('.navigation .logo').animate({
        marginTop: '48px',
        opacity: '0.8'
    }, fadeInTime).queue(function () {
        $('.right ul').animate({
            marginTop: '48px',
            opacity: '0.8'
        }, fadeInTime)
    });

    $('li > a').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('li > a').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    });

    $('.logo img').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('.logo img').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just set it's [opacity to 0.8 in the CSS](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)

Comment: @Liam how is that the same as fading it from 0 to .8 when the page loads?

Comment: No. It'll load at 0.8.

Comment: Off topic: You can simplify your code by chaining your mouseenter/leave function, or use `hover()`.

Comment: You should use CSS to take care of the hover animation after the load animation. Just set `.logo img:hover {opacity: 1.0;}` and just set up the kind of animation you want for `.logo img`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think may be your best solution... a mix of CSS and JQuery animate. This way you divide up the responsibility and don't rely so much on scripts, rather CSS. Which for animation I think if you can do it using CSS it is always better.

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fadeInTime = 1000;

    $('.navigation .logo').animate({
        marginTop: '48px',
        opacity: '0.8'
    }, fadeInTime).queue(function () {
        $('.right ul').animate({
            marginTop: '48px',
            opacity: '0.8'
        }, fadeInTime)
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
.navigation .logo, .right ul {
    opacity: 0;
}

li > a, .logo img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

li > a:hover, .logo img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that ?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/X5rN6/1/)

You just have to fit it to your needs (if you would have provided a jsFiddle or something I would have filled/updated it myself) :

HTML :

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/>
```

CSS :

```
img.faded{opacity:0.8}
img{transition: opacity 1s;}
```

JS (jQuery) :

```
$('img').addClass('faded')
    .on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('img').removeClass('faded')
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('img').addClass('faded')
    }
});
```

The logo starts at full opacity, you create the first fadeIn adding the class `.faded`, i put 0.5 opactity to make the effect more visible), and then set the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events (which are adding/removing the class as needed.
After that, you got the transition effect with CSS.

Here you don't need to animate the logo. Just add or remove the class `faded` when needed in your nesting animation.

And if you want to manage the animation of an other div after the transition, you can use the `delay()` method :

```
$('.navigation .logo').addClass('faded');
$('.right ul').delay(1000) // must match the css duration
.animate({
    marginTop: '48px',
    opacity: '0.8'
}, fadeInTime);
```